# The countdown timer will not work because it will not accept local functions

Tags: swift, xcode, countdown

Every time i try to define a function when i use the Timer.Scheduledtimer with selector. It shows the following error. I'm not sure how to get past this. Also i would like to know if there is anyway that i can connect a label to the countdown I.e. on the screen 0:59, 0:58, etc.

Thanks.

I have already tried various functions from different websites and the same problem always reemerges

```
var seconds = 0

var timer: Timer?

let countdownLabel: SKLabelNode! = {   
let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "BubbleGum")
   label.zPosition = 2
   label.color = SKColor.white
   label.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - 130, y:self.frame.size.height/15 
+ 390)
   return label
    }()
    countdownLabel.text = String(seconds)

    func counter (){
        seconds -= 1
        countdownLabel.text = String(seconds)
        if (seconds == 0)
        {
            timer!.invalidate()
        }

    }


    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, 
  selector: #selector(counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



    self.addChild(countdownLabel)



}
```

This is the error message that comes up: 
    Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'counter()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either annotate your `counter` function with @objc or use a closure

```
@objc func counter () {
   ...
}
```

Using a closure:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { timer in
    seconds -= 1
    countdownLabel.text = String(seconds)
    if (seconds == 0)
    {
        timer!.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add @objc in front of your function. Always remember to add @objc in your function if you are going to call the function inside a selector

```
class ViewControlller: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //call it like this in viewdidload/viewdidappear
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, 
      selector: #selector(counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }


      //Declare this function outside any other func like viewdidload/viewdidappear
      @objc func counter(){
            seconds -= 1
            countdownLabel.text = String(seconds)
            if (seconds == 0)
            {
                timer!.invalidate()
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: I have tried that too and another error comes up saying this: @objc can only be used with members of classes, objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes. Does this mean i have to use a specific objective c class?

Comment: I hope you have created the func counter within the class

Comment: @Drobotjosh can you show me more of this class including viewdidload and imports ?

Comment: that is not neccessary bud because it is working now. But if you want to know. I have imported SpriteKit and GamePlayKit